# how can i use retrieved objects after persistent manager closes. JDO

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, jdo, datanucleus

I thought of using detachCopy method of jdo to use objects after persistence manager connection closes but detachCopy is performance critical.

I am trying to fetch Role objects from the database. Role class is extended by StaticRole class.

```
    PersistenceManager pm = PersistenceFactory
            .getPersistenceManager(clientId);
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        List<Role> allRoles = (List<Role>) pm
                .detachCopyAll(getAllRoles(pm));
        tx.commit();
        return allRoles;
    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        pm.close();
    }
```

Here i do not want to use detachCopy method coz it is slowing down my code. I tried makeTransient method also but it didn't work recursively i.e. it is giving me roles but static roles data is lost. I also tried useFetchplan with makeTransient but that is also taking time.

Please someone help me out.

Comment: `makeTransient` has a method to respect a fetch plan.

Comment: @BillyFrost  i tried the fetch plan also but it is also performance heavy. I just making a get call so i dont want to take too much time.

Comment: If fields need loading ... as per the fetch plan ... then they need loading. No idea what is performance heavy in that context